# How to enable button using reactive forms in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a input field and a button.When the field is not empty the button should be enabled.But here in my case i am already passing input value.so it should be enabled but this is not happening.It is being enabled when i type anything in the input field.Any info on how to achieve it.below is my code

```
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  hello = "hello world";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('',[<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)])
    });
  }

  onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: userForm, valid: boolean }) {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(value,valid);
  }
}
```

here is my html code

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" validate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [value]="hello">
  </div>
  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="userForm.invalid">Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Whats that validate attribute doing on the form element? And if Im understanding you correctly, you want the button to be enabled whenever the forms input is filled in. So you are looking for the 'dirty' property of the form, correct?

Comment: yeah..as u can see i am getting input value from the component.So its already filled and the button should be enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the **[value]="hello"** from your input as they should go in the `new FormControl(value, [validators], [asyncValidators])` for reactive forms.

something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(this.hello, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)])
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have tried this method and it works.But is it not possible to achieve that in the way i gave it??

Comment: The problem with mixing that approach is the input renders with a value, but is not invoking any of the reactiveForms functions to propagate it up to the formGroup you're creating and using in your [disabled] statement. If it worked please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use reactive forms, like this:

- step1: import ReactiveForm, FormBuilder, Validators
- step2: declare FormGroup object and inject form builder into constructor
- step3: init your form group
- step4: using the reactive form in the same way as you did but with some changes

Code:

```
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm: FormGroup;
  firstName: string;

  constructor(private _formBuilder:FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.firstName);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" name="userForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
        <p *ngIf="userForm.controls.firstName.invalid && (userForm.controls.firstName.dirty || userForm.controls.firstName.touched)"> Error message </p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="userForm.invalid">Submit </button>
    </form>
```